# sqoop import sql server only found dbo tables

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop, sql-server-2016, mapr

I was trying to import data from SQL Server using SQOOP. but I found a weird situation

Sqoop list-tales only found table with dbo.**** , other than that, Sqoop cannot list
But on SQL server, I can see other tables listed

[List of Tables from the SQOOP command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbFI3.png)

[List of Tables from SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwWDx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check whether any access rules are set for rest of the tables in sql server for particular user.

Comment: Hello, 
I was able to trouble shot the problem myself. Solution is to define the schema in SQL JDBC Connection String.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to trouble shoot the issue myself. 
The Root Cause: Without mention Schema in connection String, the default schema will be always dbo 
the solution: in JDBC connection string, please mention the Schema is the schema that you want SQOOP to point to.

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;schema=[theschemaname]

have fun !